# How can I select specific nested element with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have this markup

```
     <table id="myexample" class="myclass">
     <thead>
     <tr>
     <th><input type="checkbox" value="tableoption1"> Username</th>
     <th> Something </th>
     <th> Something </th>
     <th> Something </th>
     <th> Something </th>
     <th> Something </th>
      <th> Something </th>

     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td> <input id="user1" type="checkbox" value="tableoption1">  John Smith </a></td>
     <td> Nickname</td>
     <td> Address </td>
     <td> Registerd</td>
     <td>10-10-2014 </td>
     <td>09-11-2014</td>
     <td>03-02-2014</td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

**How can I select with Jquery the input element with id=user1 ?**

I have already tried this but doesnt work

```
 $("#users tbody tr td input").click(function(){ 
      alert ("success");
 });
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: You have to read this: http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/jquery-basics and possibly this: http://www.cssbasics.com/introduction-to-css/

Comment: `id`'s are unique so there is no need to think about nesting; just ask for it directly

Comment: what is `users`? What is with the random `</a>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to control when checkbox is checked:

```
$('#user1').click(function(){ 
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        alert("checked!");
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks @Borachio this also works. Is there a way to select all ids that contain the "user" for example to multiple select user1,user2 user3 etc etc without writing smt like this $('#user1, #user2, #user3') ?

Comment: In this case, it's better work with classes, like: <input type="checkbox" class=".userChoice"/> and in jquery: $(".userChoice") without hash character. check: http://jsfiddle.net/pxeLgy6n/

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$('#user1').click(function(){ 
      alert ("success");
 });
```

Comment: If you got an answer please submit it.

Comment: @Flopert thanks this worked fine.Is there a way to select all classes starting with user for example to be able to select at once user1,user2 etc etc ?

Comment: If I understood correctly what you want to do, you can just pass another id like this: $('#user1, #user2, #user3')

Comment: Yes but if there is a way to declare all classes starting with "user" instead of declaring user1,user2 ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$( "#user1" )
```

Try this I think thats what you are asking.